# How does it work when flying through a Schengen country to make a connection?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, connecting-flights

Can someone explain how this works for a journey from Lviv via Warsaw to New York?

If I have a flight originating outside the Schengen area, with a separately-ticketed connection in a Schengen country to take a flight to the US, do you need to go through a passport control in Warsaw if you have no baggage? For the sake of scenario let's take WizzAir Lviv to Warsaw and LOT from Warsaw to New York.

Does each airport in the EU allow you to stay in a non-Schengen area and web check in to proceed further (if no baggage)?

For some reason I thought that not all airports would have [airside] transit and, in some cases, one would have to go through passport control first and then go back through security?

P.S. Sorry, I edited my question with more accurate examples.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Andre. My edit was to make your question a bit clearer, and to add tags, as appropriate. Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: You might check with the airlines involved. You might also consider internet check-in, and ask the outgoing airline about the procedure.

Comment: Hi Andre, many airports even have staffed desks that allow you to get a boarding pass printed without passing through immigration or security.  I do not know the situation at [either of Berlin's currently operating airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airports_of_Berlin), however.  Which one will you be flying through?

Comment: Ooh, also *I do not see any direct flights from Berlin to Los Angeles.  **If your flight connects at another airport in the Schengen area then you will certainly need a Schengen visa because the flight from Berlin to the connecting airport will be an internal Schengen flight.***  If you want accurate advice, please edit your question with the complete itinerary.

Comment: @phoog the edit on the question removed the fact that is was apparently a rhetorical question and Moscow-Belin-Los Angeles was just an hypothetical example (which is indeed not possible without an additional connection).

Comment: @jcaron thanks for pinging me. I will let my comment stand since it at least points out one of the many possible problems that someone considering such an itinerary should keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

**Most** (but not all; one notable exception is Berlin's TXL) major airports in the Schengen area are set up such that passengers arriving on a non-Schengen flight can proceed directly to the non-Schengen departure lounge without passing immigration (but passing a transfer security check depending on where they flew in from).

This route will not give the passenger a possibility to pick up and re-check baggage.

Often, but not always, there will be transfer desks where transiting passenger can check in for their next flight. With the spread of online/mobile checkin this is becoming less important, though.

What *remains* important is that for separately ticketed flights, a passenger will **probably not be allowed to board** the flight *towards* the Schengen airport unless they have a passport or visa that *would* allow them to pass through immigration. In case of a missed or cancelled connection, the inbound airline would be on the hook to the host country's authorities for transporting a passenger without sufficient documentation, and there's no good reason why they would accept that risk.

---

Smaller non-hub airports will not necessarily have a non-Schengen waiting area. They sometimes do immigration checks right at the gate.

Comment: Transit without formally entering Germany is possible at Berlin Tegel (TXL), but not possible at Berlin Schönefeld (SXF). At least according to the German Foreign Office: https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/newsroom/buergerservice-faq-kontakt/faq/33-airporttransitvisum/606472